# Can a stud finder reliably detect HVAC sheetmetal?

Tags: tools

Thread title says it all. I'm installing can lights in a basement and want to make sure I clear the HVAC return when drilling holes. If a stud finder can't detect that, what's the best way to verify it's location?

Comment: It depends on what the duct work is made of. If it is metal and in contact with the sheet rock a stud finder will detect the edge if zeroed on an area that doesn't have ducting. If it is plastic the stud finder will not see it. Some  contractors use the space between the floor joists for the duct to make more head room. If you have this kind of construction don't put a fixture in that run or you will kill the air flow.